# NSData from NSKeyedArchiver to NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nsdata, nskeyedarchiver

I'm trying to convert NSData generated from NSKeyedArchiver to an NSString so that I can pass it around and eventually convert it back to NSData. I have to pass this as a string (I'm using three20 URL passing). I've gone through various encodings, UTF8, ASCII, etc. and can't get anything to work. NSKeyedArchiver says that the NSData is formated as a property list: NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0.

Does anyone have any idea how I can convert this NSData to a String and back again? Size of the string isn't an issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you want is:

```
id<nscoding> obj;

NSData * data     = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:obj];
NSString * string = [data base64EncodedString];
```

And then the other way around

```
NSString * string;

NSData * data    = [NSData dataFromBase64String:string];
id<nscoding> obj = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]
```

You can add base64EncodedString and dataFromBase64String: with the NSData category available here [NSData+Base64](https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64) but it is now included by default

Comment: Note: Now it is`[data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:`

Answer (score 2):

**iOS 9.2.1, Xcode 7.2.1, ARC enabled**

> base64EncodedString, dataFromBase64String: depreciated after iOS 7.0

**Updated solution:**

*Encode to string:*

```
id<nscoding> obj;

NSData *data     = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:obj];
NSString *string = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];
```

*Decode to data:*

```
NSString *string;

NSData *data    = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:string options:(NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters)];
id<nscoding> obj = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

**Note: This is very useful when working with keychain to store a dictionary of key/value pairs into kSecValueData.**

Hope this helps someone!  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

All you should have to do is something like this:

```
NSData *dataFromString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", yourString] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

then to extract the data:

```
NSString *stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataFromString encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, and I'm not sure why, this doesn't seem to work. I get a very short string, for example "bplist00Ô" as my output.

Comment: That's definitely odd.  I'm going to test a couple things as alternatives and get back to you with (hopefully) something that does work

Comment: What I posted did the trick for me, though I noticed that if you decode the data into a string from a different method than when you encode it, you get faults.  This can be fixed by adding `retain` to the `dataFromString` instance after you encode your string.  Hopefully this fixes the issue you were having.  If not, there is another possible route to take if necessary