# Encoding for converting between NSString to NSData and back

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, nsstring, nsdata

I'm trying to encrypt/decrypt an NSString and return the original string in the end. Here's how I convert the string to a data object:

`NSData *string_data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

And after that data has been encrypted/decrypted I want it back to the original string by doing:

`NSString *to_string = [NSString stringWithCString:[decrypted_data bytes] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

The encoding seems to match, but I still get a null  when I try to print out `to_string` to the console. I've tried all sorts of encoding settings. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103579/nsdata-from-nskeyedarchiver-to-nsstring/17593009#17593009 Use base64Encoding

Comment: I do *not* think that is a possible duplicate. That question is about converting *arbitrary* data to a string for passing it around. This question is about converting decrypted data back to the original string.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
NSString *to_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:string_data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It is not safe to use `stringWithCString` because the `bytes` buffer you get from NSData is not guaranteed to be null-terminated.

Comment: That doesn't work either, also you have to specify the encoding not just the data passed.That was the first method I've tried and setting it to `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:string_data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` didn't work either.

Comment: @labdulle: Have you verified that the decrypted data `decrypted_data` is exactly equal to the original data `string_data`?

Comment: That is a good question. It seems there is a problem with the decryption. I'm an idiot.