# How to convert a keyedArchiver to a string and back again

Tags: nsstring, nsdata, nskeyedarchiver, nspasteboard

I want to convert a custom object into a propertyList. Then later I want to retrieve it via NSOutlineView.  I use a NSKeyedArchiver/unArchiver to convert my object to and from a NSData.

In my custom object (OutlineItem):

```
-(id)pasteboardPropertyListForType:(NSPasteboardType)type
{
if ([[[info draggingPasteboard] types] containsObject: kPrivateDragUTI])
{
     NSData *itemData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
     NSString* itemString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:itemData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
     return itemString;
}
```

In NSOutlineView:

```
- (id<NSPasteboardWriting>)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView pasteboardWriterForItem:(id)item
{
   OutlineItem* anItem = item;
   return anItem;
}
```

Later:

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)destinationOutlineView
             acceptDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info item:(id)destinationParentItem
             childIndex:(NSInteger)destinationIndex
{    
    NSPasteboard *pboard = [info draggingPasteboard];
    OutlineItem* pbItem = nil;
    if ([[pboard types] containsObject: kPrivateDragUTI])
    {
        NSString* stringForData = [[info draggingPasteboard] stringForType:kPrivateDragUTI];
        NSData *data = [stringForData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

StringForData looks OK, but data is nil at this point.

Why is data nil?

Comment: What is the value of `stringForData`? Are all characters in the string ASCII characters? Do you need the string, can't you put the data on the pasteboard?

Comment: stringForData begins like this: @"bplist00Ô\0\x01\0\x02\0\x03\0\x04\0\x05\0\x06\0\a\0\nX$versionY$archiverT$topX$objects\x12\0\x01\U00000086 _\x10\x0fNSKeyedArchiverÑ\0\b\0\tTroot\U00000080\x01¯\x11\x03û\0\v\0\f\0\x17\0\x18\0\x1c\0#\0)\0-\01\08\09\0A\0B\0E\0H\0M\0S\0T\0a\0g\0h\0k\0o\0r\0v\0|\0}\0\U00000082\0\U00000088\0\U00000089\0\U0000008c\0\U00000090\0\U00000093... According to Apple's doc, NSData does not implement NSPasteboardWriting protocol

Comment: The characters in stringForData appear to be ASCII.

Comment: This post promises to do just this.  I'll test it and report back.  Until then, don't spend your time on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103579/nsdata-from-nskeyedarchiver-to-nsstring

Comment: The updated solution in this post works perfectly:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103579/nsdata-from-nskeyedarchiver-to-nsstring